# how to undo typing in browser address bar

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I sometimes type something into my address bar, and then I decide I don't want to go forwards but still need the original address. I end up having to reload the page in order to restore the address. Is there a way to undo typing in the address bar without reloading the page?

I'd love if there is a non-browser-specific way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> and it worked.

*(sometimes it might take more than just one <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>)*

Comment: this should be added to the google chrome shortcut keys documemnt